# Vim colorscheme is not working for large files

Tags: vim, editor

I'm new to Vim. So, I copied the .vimrc file from the internet and set the color scheme as gruvbox. But for files containing more than 1500 lines, it is not working after line 1250. It is showing plain text with green font color after line 1250. How to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

**.vimrc file:**

```
syntax on

set guicursor=

set nohlsearch
set hidden
set nu
set nowrap
set smartcase
set noswapfile
set nobackup
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
set undofile
set incsearch
set termguicolors
set scrolloff=8
set cmdheight=2
set updatetime=50
set shortmess+=c

set colorcolumn=80
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=0 guibg=lightgrey
let g:gruvbox_contrast_dark = 'hard'
if exists('+termguicolors')
    let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
    let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
endif
let g:gruvbox_invert_selection='0'

colorscheme gruvbox
set background=dark

if executable('rg')
    let g:rg_derive_root='true'
endif
```

Comment: This is not an example of a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You will have more luck with people answering your question if you shorten your `.vimrc` to the smallest one that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why they haven't fixed this bug, but the fix is this:

```
syntax sync fromstart
```

Comment: and adding `:map \c :syntax sync fromstart<CR>` in your ~/.vimrc allows to refresh simply with '\r'